# Opinions: Circuit_macros or circuitikz ? what is better?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, circuitikz, circuits

I'd gladly read your opinions on Circuit_macros **pros** and cons, as well as yours on circuitikz. Gives the macro more variables to play with? Is the circuitikz language easier?

Macro use seems far more difficult, doesnt it? It is worthy the more complex Macro to learn and so more to develop more accurate circuits? What do you **recommend** a newbie in tikz, a familared with tikz user and a pro?
[image]

PD: [macro's web](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/CMman.pdf)!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I fear your question provokes opinion-based answers ;-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  This is question is rather opened, see the guidelines http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask .  Perhaps you could improve by making it more specific, giving a particular type of circuit you would like to set and what you have tried yourself.

Comment: The best would be to have the component library from Circuit Macro and the ease of use provided by TiKZ!

Comment: I fear you are right @AndrewSwann, this question is too subjective, so it could be removed. Anyway I hope it will help everyone who doubt if macro circuit learning is worthy.

Comment: By the way what you had as an example is a flow chart or a block diagram so it might be slightly misleading.

Answer (score 2):

This web helped me to decide, it isnt complex enough but it may guide one
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Electronics/Programs